# SIGSEGV while converting 1 bit image data into 8 bit

Tags: c, image-processing, segmentation-fault

I have image data stored in an `unsigned char` array. The data is in the form of `RGB0RGB0` per byte, that is, two pixels are covered per byte and after each `RGB` a `0` is padded so as to align it in multiples of `4`. For further processing I need to convert this 1 bit per color component data into 8 bits per component, i.e., 1 byte for each color. So what I am doing is, for every byte I check the MSB, if it is `1`, I set a byte to `0xFF` else I leave it `0`. The code I have written is as follows:

```
void
convert_pixels(unsigned char *pixdata,
               unsigned char *convertedpix,
               int width,
               int height)
{
    int i,j,k, count=0;
    unsigned int mask;
    unsigned char temp;
    for(i=0;i<height;i++)
    {
        count=0;
        for(j=0;j<width;j++)
        {
            temp = *(pixdata+i*width+j);
            for (mask = 0x80; mask != 0; mask >>= 1)
            {
                if ((temp & mask) && mask!=0x10 && mask!=0x01)
                    *(convertedpix+i*width*6+count)=0xFF;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It gives SIGSEGV on execution. `bt` on `gdb` gives:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004014b0 in convert_pixels (pixdata=0x7f008a0cf010 '\377' <repeats 200 times>..., 
    pixdata@entry=0x7f00967e2010 'w' <repeats 200 times>..., convertedpix=0x7f00967e2010 'w' <repeats 200 times>..., 
    convertedpix@entry=0x7f008a0cf010 '\377' <repeats 200 times>..., width=width@entry=4958, height=height@entry=7017) at image_convert.c:166
#1  0x0000000000401007 in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at image_convert.c:355
```

The array `convertedpix` has been allocated memory which is exactly `6` times that of `pixdata`:

```
if(header.cupsBitsPerColor==1)
        {
            convertedpix = (unsigned char*)calloc(header.cupsWidth * header.cupsHeight*6,
                                                                                        sizeof(unsigned char));
            convert_pixels(pixdata, convertedpix, header.cupsWidth,
                                         header.cupsHeight);
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the array pointed by `convertedpix` is 6 times bigger than array pointed by `pixdata`?

Comment: @LPs yes I have allocated memory to `convertedpix` which is exactly `6` times of `pixdata`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get segmentation fault because you increment count and width in a way that they don't match the memory layout and eventually you are writing out of the memory allocated. If you move width and hight, then count should go from 0 to 5 in loop accordingly.

```
void
convert_pixels(unsigned char *pixdata, unsigned char *convertedpix,
               int width, int height) {
    int i, j, k;
    unsigned int mask;
    unsigned char temp;
    for(i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            k = 0;
            temp = *(pixdata + i * width + j);
            for (mask = 0x80; mask != 0; mask >>= 1) {
                if (mask != 0x10 && mask != 0x01) { /* code below will be 
                                                     * executed 6 times */
                    if (temp & mask) { 
                        *(convertedpix + i * width + k) = 0xFF;
                    } else {
                        *(convertedpix + i * width + k) = 0;
                    }
                    ++k;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, please add a check of `calloc` return value (maybe there is a problem with memory allocation):

```
if (header.cupsBitsPerColor==1) {
    convertedpix = (unsigned char*) calloc(header.cupsWidth *
                                  header.cupsHeight * 6, sizeof(unsigned char));
    if (convertedpix != NULL) {
        convert_pixels(pixdata, convertedpix, header.cupsWidth, 
                                                      header.cupsHeight);
    } else {
        /* handle error */
    }
}
```

---

[Usage](https://ideone.com/DTt4Ym)

Comment: I tried it but it also gives SIGSEGV. This won't work as the width of the `convetedpix` is exactly `6` times `pixdata`. Your solution does not take that into consideration

Comment: @Pranjal Sure it wasn't working because it was designed for 8 times bigger array. Please check updated code.

Comment: Do you still get SIGSEGV? Could you please paste complete example?

Comment: @Pranjal I would like to see how you allocate arrays and call convert_pixels

Comment: I have added it. Please have a look

Comment: I just checked it and there is no problem with memory allocation

Comment: @where_is_tftp, Yes your solution is right, I did a small mistake while passing the parameters to the function. Thanks